# Checkbox - When disabled want to looks like enabled

Tags: css, checkbox

I have `checkboxes` with classic css style on my page and when check box is disabled it looks different then when it is enabled. I don't want to change look. Enabled look = Disabled look.?

Comment: *"Enabled look = Disabled look."* so you want to make it really confusing for user?

Comment: don't worry about users

Comment: I don't think so. You can use `-webkit-appearance` to give it a new appearance but it will still have the disabled styling.

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271463/how-to-style-a-disabled-checkbox

This is terrible UX though